# Is JMeter is going to be paid as Oracle decides for Java post 1.8v?

Tags: java, jmeter, java-11

As we all aware about that Java is paid since January, 2019 and JMeter is java based application. Can we expect this effect on JMeter as well because Apache would have to pay to Oracle for Java usage to work on JMeter for further verisons!

Please provide insights on this if anyone have.Please correct me if i am not correct.

Comment: First: you are not *required* to purchase support for Java from Oracle even if you use the Oracle JDK (but then you don't get security fixes). Secondly: you can use any non-Oracle JDK/JRE if you like. Third: the publisher of an application never needs to purchase support, only those who use the application.

Comment: This community is for library questions, not about discussing licencsing models, legal advice, or such things ...

Comment: Will take care henceforth but i asked because i didn't get the exact answer from anywhere.

Comment: I am using Java-11.0.3, I am getting this info while launching jmeter. `Error: Java version -- 11.0.3 -- is too low to run JMeter. Needs a Java version greater than or equal to 1.7.0
errorlevel=3`
Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely not !

In any case, Apache would not have to pay Oracle, as it is the user of Java for JMeter (as for any other Java application) who would pay.

**But, there is no such risk anyway.**

JMeter needs Java >=8 (Java 9 and 10 are intermediate and not advised).

Java is provided by:

- Oracle
- Other vendors (IBM)
- OpenJDK

As of Java 8:

- Oracle is free
- OpenJDK is free
- IBM Java SDK is free

Only Oracle JDK >= 11 is subject to a paid support, OpenJDK is not.
And as you know there are already LTS (Long Term Support) free offers for jdk currently at least by [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/) and [Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013).

**So no risk at all for Apache JMeter !**

You can see that the jmeter github project runs on OpenJdk through TravisCI:

- https://travis-ci.org/apache/jmeter/

Comment: Thanks for the info! Will use this valuable info further to my blogs!

Comment: But JDK 11 is LTS and is free, so why should it be paid?