# Does JMeter works on OpenJDK 13?

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, java-13

I've did web search `jmeter and openjdk 13` and found only that relevant post: [Is JMeter is going to be paid as Oracle decides for Java post 1.8v?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139975/is-jmeter-is-going-to-be-paid-as-oracle-decides-for-java-post-1-8v):

> JMeter needs Java >=8 (**Java 9 and 10 are intermediate and not
>   advised**).

On [Apache JMeter page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JMeterAndOperatingSystemsTested) last JMeter version mentioned is `JMeter 2.5.x (JVM 1.5+)`.

How does JMeter works on latest OpenJDK 13?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latest JMeter 5.2.1 works with [Java 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192473/unusable-dropdown-menus-in-jmeter-5-2-1-on-ubuntu-19-04)

> JMeter works for me on a freshly installed Ubuntu 19.04 Desktop with either OpenJDK 13 (installed from the Ubuntu repo) as well as Oracle JDK 13

JMeter officially don't limit java version in [requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#java_versions):

> JMeter is **compatible with Java 8 or higher**. We highly advise you to **install latest minor version of your major version** for security and performance reasons.

Also you can see JMeter is tested with Java 13 on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/apache/jmeter/)

Comment: thanx, I was concerned with quote in my question "Java 9 and 10 are intermediate and not advised". I don't know where it came from to appear in that answer.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov It's an old documentation

Comment: maybe, it was in Jan 2019 answer.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov you are right, I was talking about second link, The first link just comment about Java 9,10 are non long term versions and changes in oracle license https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html

Answer (score 1):

Why it shouldn't? Java is backwards compatible and as long as software doesn't rely on removed APIs it should be running better on newer JDK/JRE. Moreover as per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article you should be using:

1. The latest JMeter version
2. The latest Java version (better 64-bit server JRE or JDK)
3. The latest version of [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) (if any are used in your tests)

[image]

Just in case you can get familiarized with [Oracle JDK Migration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-FAD4E80D-64BA-42AC-A682-38D06EE61AC6)